# Get current state of caps/scroll/numlock in windows w/o using Peek/ReadConsoleInput()

Tags: windows

I'm programming a Windows console application in plain C and using PeekConsoleInput/ReadConsoleInput to get keystrokes from the user and process them.

I need to get the current state of the Caps Lock, Scroll Lock, and Num Lock keys when the program starts, *before* the user has entered anything. Meaning there would be no KEY_EVENTs in the message queue to process.

Is this possible to do? If so, how? I've looked at most of the functions in wincon.h and nothing seems appropriate.

Answer (score 2):

You can call GetAsyncKeyState three times, and it will usually work, but there are a few cases where it still won't work for you.  The arguments for your three calls would be VK_CAPITAL, VK_SCROLL, and VK_NUMLOCK.

Comment: Thanks! I'm now using GetKeyState() instead of Async, but it works fine too.